# Deploying two angular application on a single aws ec2 istance

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, amazon-ec2

Trying to deploy two angular application (First one is for front end user interface, second one is for admin panel) for my ecommerce web platform on aws ec2 istance NGINX server.

```
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # angular app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /opt/app-web;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  #admin app
  location /app-admin/ {
    root /opt/app-admin;
    try_files $uri /index.html
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}
```

Here I am unable to open the admin panel as it redirects to app-one. If there, Please suggest me a better way.

Comment: Is your admin app build with a base-href set correctly? Angular needs to know if it is running in a subfolder..

Comment: yes, In package json I have mentioned --base-href.  It is working in my test server with subfolder. I think issue is in this nginx config to redirect